# SSH Key Permissions chmod settings?

Tags: ssh, permissions

I need to use SSH on my machine to access my website and its databases (setting up a symbolic link- but I digress).

#### Following problem

I enter the command:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

To generate public/private dsa key pair. I save it in the default (`/home/user/.ssh/id_dsa`) and enter Enter passphrase twice.

Then I get this back:

```
WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!  
Permissions 0755 for '/home/etc.ssh/id_rsa' are too open. It is recommended that your private key files are NOT accessible by others. This private key will be ignored. bad permissions: ignore key: [then the FILE PATH in VAR/LIB/SOMEWHERE]
```

Now to work round this I then tried

```
sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa         sudo chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

But shortly after my computer froze up, and on logging back on there was a `could not find .ICEauthority error`.

I got round this problem and deleted the SSH files but want to be able to use the correct permissions to avoid these issues in future.

How should I set up ICEauthority, or where should I save the SSH Keys- or what permissions should they have? Would using a virtual machine be best?

This is all very new and I am on a very steep learning curve, so any help appreciated.

Comment: typo- sorry just one set of keys was generated!

Comment: permissions to .ssh dir are equally important as key permissions. It should be 600. To fix it run : `chmod -R 600 ~/.ssh`.

Comment: actually .ssh directory permissions need to be 700 not 600. The execute permission is the one that gives you access to what is inside that directory. So the correct commands should be `chmod 700 $HOME/.ssh` and `chmod 600 $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: The error about .ICEauthority is not related to the `chmod` commands you show. Either it's a coincidence or you ran some other commands that you aren't showing us.

Answer (score 216):

`chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (i.e. `chmod u=rw,go= ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) are correct.

`chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` (i.e. `chmod a=r,u+w ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) would also be correct, but `chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` (i.e. `chmod a=r,u+w ~/.ssh/id_rsa`) would not be. Your public key can be public, what matters is that your private key is private.

Also your `.ssh` directory itself must be writable only by you: `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` or `chmod u=rwx,go= ~/.ssh`. You of course need to be able to read it and access files in it (execute permission). It isn't directly harmful if others can read it, but it isn't useful either.

You don't need `sudo`. Don't use `sudo` to manipulate your own files, that can only lead to mistakes.

The error about `.ICEauthority` is not related to the `chmod` commands you show. Either it's a coincidence or you ran some other commands that you aren't showing us.

Comment: What do the permissions on the ~/.ssh/known_hosts need to be?

Comment: I want to add to the answers above that for me my home directory (`~/`) also needed to have the permissions `755`, regardless of the permissions of `~/.ssh` and the files therein. (This was on a Synology NAS, might not apply to all linuxes)

Comment: @terdon: So, are you saying that we should have accepted [Scrooge McDuck’s suggested edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/342901)?  And that Gilles should override us and accept it?   (Note that it contains an error.)

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' I find silly to state that my edit does not improve readibility; if not so, papers would only contain inline equations. On other side I can't understand how an extremely simple and properly highlighted table explaining how to read those chmod can be said *superfluous*; if that's the case, then why posting commands in the first place and just not point users to bash scripts all the times.

Comment: That said, I just want my answer to be shown for very practical reasons: people ask me how to enable ssh all the time and they find very annoying to copy-paste the many inline commands from Gilles' answer, which among other things they usually find difficult to understand and remember. 

I don't care if you consider it an improved version of this answer or a completely new one, I only care for people I redirect here (myself included) to have their question answered in the most efficient way.

Comment: @fpmurphy: in fact when I was told at first (9 months ago) that my edit was too far away from the original, I reposted as a separate answer. On readability I personally refer to voters' judgement; in due time we can have a fair verdict on that. Of course, to me the 3 upvotes and the in-person considerations it received confirm that already.

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck I find your version hard to understand. You removed part of the explanations, leaving some code snippets with no clear meaning. Making the code snippets multiline doesn't make them more readable. The explanation of the chmod commands _is_ superfluous: explaining chmod is very far from the topic of the question.

Comment: I don't want to convince *you* that my edit is more readable, I just want it shown somewhere on this page because *I* find it more readable. About chmod, I believe in this situation some context is needed.

Comment: Since it clearly seem to me that we can't reach a compromise about this answer's syntax highlighting, inline code positioning and general information context, I simply demand to have my edit posted as a separate answer, like it has already been for 9 months. I am sure in due time consensus through further improvements will be reached.

Comment: I have reposted a barebone version of my edit to make it different enough from yours to avoid this controversy.

Comment: chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts If known_hosts is deleted the system will generate a new empty one with the correct permissions.

Answer (score 34):

```bsh
    # Set public/private key permissions

    # Octal form
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

    # Equivalent literal form
    chmod u=rw,go= ~/.ssh/id_rsa ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

    # Optional: make public key readable
    chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub # chmod a=r,u+w ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

    # Set directory permissions
    chmod 700 ~/.ssh # chmod u=rwx,go= ~/.ssh

    # Legend for literal form
    # +: allow       -: deny         =: reset and allow
    # u: user        r: read
    # g: group       w: write
    # o: others      x: execute
    # a: all
```

Comment: Great explanations, but whats `a` in `a=r`

Comment: `a` means `all`