# "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" is always modified by other process

Tags: linux, ssh, sshd

I am not familiar with sshd process; and I am trying to enable remote ssh login without password, and I have inserted my public key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the server side, and it works on one of the remote system, not the other.

I noticed the following entries in my /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the non-working remote system,

```
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile /var/ssh/%u/ak
```

since I have my public key inserted in .ssh/authorized_keys, I tried to change the above to

```
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile /var/ssh/%u/ak
```

This seems to allow me to remote ssh without password, however, I noticed that the file was reset back every few hours, and I have to key in password for SSH again.

any idea what is happening with the config file here?

Thanks!

Comment: Purely from the `sshd` perspective, it shouldn't matter whether it's commented or not, since that's the default value. However, it is concerning that it's being reverted periodically. That definitely should not be happening. The reason you can't use password-less login on one your systems is more likely to be a [permissions issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257590/100397).

Comment: It is pretty common that some services require to change AK to /var. For example some web managed system need to modify AK from httpd, but usually security rules prevent httpd related process to access user home, thus it need to be in /var

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You could use [tools](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/25145/cli-tool-to-use-fanotify) implementing `fanotify()` kernel APIs. For instance [fanotify-cmd](https://github.com/peadar/fanotify-cmd) works perfectly. There's no need to edit any system files or parse logs.

  ```bash
  ./fm -a /etc/passwd
  checking for events FAN_ACCESS
  mask: FAN_ACCESS, fd: 4, pid: 203188, file: /etc/passwd, command: bash 
  mask: FAN_ACCESS, fd: 4, pid: 203190, file: /etc/passwd, command: 
  mask: FAN_ACCESS, fd: 4, pid: 203321, file: /etc/passwd, command: ls --color=auto -l /etc/passwd
  ```

  Ubuntu and Fedora include `fatrace` which is a really nice well maintained utility.

  ```
  sudo fatrace --timestamp --filter=WD
  ```
- Or you could use`auditd`. Since it's a system daemon, you'll need to edit an auditd system configuration file in `/etc`. There are plenty of manuals on the net how to use them, e.g. on [stackexchange itself](https://serverfault.com/questions/320716/find-out-which-process-is-changing-a-file).

  `inotifywait` unfortunately doesn't work for this use case as it merely shows the files being accessed or modified, it doesn't show what process does it.

Comment: thank you @Artem S. Tashkinov
It turns out that there is puppet service running and always modifying my sshd config.

Comment: @sqr great! What did you use? `inotifywait`? You may mark my answer as an answer ;-)

Comment: Hi  @Artem, inotifywait doesn't print out the process name which triggered the change, auditd does. Thanks!

Comment: @sqr I've known about `fanotify()` for years now but was always too lazy to find utilities using it. Looks like they exist and they are very easy to use. Could be useful for you.

Comment: thanks. I understand this is a system API instead of utility, so I have to write a short C program to use it?

Comment: The "tools" is a link to ready to use tools. "fanotify-cmd" is also a link to the tool whose output I've showed here which needs to be compiled but it doesn't need anything except g++ and glibc-devel.

Comment: thank you @Artem!

Comment: You're very welcome. I wish distros packaged `fanotify-cmd` because it's so much more powerful than inotifywatch.