# what creates ~/.debug/ folder?

Tags: ubuntu

I noticed there is ~/.debug/ contain probes and elf files for many libraries. What program actually create this? structure like this:

```
.debug/
├── .build-id
├── home
├── [kernel.kallsyms]
├── usr
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/669423/260833

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This directory is created by `perf` command.

[perf.wiki.kernel.org:  The build-id cache](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial#The_build-id_cache)

> Given that build-id are immutable, they uniquely identify a binary. If a binary is recompiled, a new build-id is generated and a new copy of the ELF images is saved in the cache. The cache is saved on disk in a directory which is by default `$HOME/.debug`.